# Interrupt a thread running Stream API operation

Tags: java

Suppose there is a stream operation which takes a while to complete, like:

```
Files.walk(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/usr/local"))
        .mapToLong(path -> path.toFile().length())
        .sum();
```

How this operation can be interrupted when run in a separate thread?

I can check `Thread.isInterrupted()` in an intermediate operation but it looks rather messy:

```
.peek(e -> {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interruption requested");
    }
  })
```

Comment: I would be moderately surprised if there were a better alternative than what you had.  Normal operations that don't block aren't generally interruptible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is such a good idea. This code never gets out of the while loop despite throwing the RuntimeException inside peek(...)

```
package so;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CrazyClass {

    static class RunMe implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Files.walk(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("....."))
                .mapToLong(path -> path.toFile().length())
                .peek(e -> {
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Interruption requested");
                        }
                })
                .sum();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread(new RunMe());
        th.start();
        try{
            while(th.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE){
                th.interrupt();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x){

        }
    }
}
```